# Perspective bug

Tags: css, perspective

[image]

I'm having the following div structure

```
<div class="a">
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
</div>

div.a {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px; 
  perspective: 1000px;
  -ms-perspective: 1000px; 
}
div.a div {
  float: left;
  width:33.33333333333333%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden
  background: transparent url(someimage) no-repeat;
}
```

All the divs (div.a div) are positioned with js and are having a background image so that it appears a single image (a image is broken in to 6parts)

The problem is that I'm having a line between div childs.
If I remove perspective everything is fine.

The div structure and css class presented here is just for simplifying the code.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot or a fiddle because I understand your problem but I can't visualize it.

Comment: I added the image. It has happening only on a specific resolutions. For the momment I solve it by removing perspective after a square has been animated.

Comment: So is it solved? Make sure that there is no space between the `div`

Comment: is not the space that is causing this problem. As I sai, the problem is not always visible. At different resolutions it is showing up or not.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by removing perspective after a square has been animated
I also use the following structure for a square

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

the perspective is applied to the parent and removed after animation (you can't apply it to the child anyway)